# Can I create a documentation topic to link a Stack Overflow question with useful information?

Tags: support, documentation

One of my favorites Stack Overflow question is this one:

*[What is your most productive shortcut with Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)*

I find it quite valuable for Vim users. Now, I didn't find this much information available in the Vim part of the Documentation site.

I thought it would fit perfectly in the "Tips and tricks to boost productivity" topic (https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim/3382/tips-and-tricks-to-boost-productivity).

Is there a problem to create a topic just to link a Stack Overflow question with useful information?

In the case of this is not a proper way to do it, what would be the correct way to put the valuable info on that question on the Documentation site?

Comment: I think that would be a pretty crappy use of a topic personally

Comment: The best way to do it, IMO was if @JimDennis himself would like to put this info on documentation site.

Comment: +1 for good question (not agreement)